# Can jQuery click to call hover functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hover

**HTML :**

```
<div class="hover">hover</div>

<div class="click">click</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    alert("hovered!");
});

$('.click').click(function(){
    $('.hover').hover();
});
```

This code isn't work , But can I do like `$('.hover').hover()` ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/wbFLH/

---

**PS : I know I can do like**

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    func();
});

$('.click').click(function(){
    func();
});

function func() {
    alert("something")
}
```

But I want to know , Can I hover and call hover function via using "click" function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.hover()` uses `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` so you have to trigger `.mouseenter/.mouseleave` instead.

From [jQuery .hover docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#entry-longdesc)

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.
>
> Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut) is shorthand for:
>
> $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    $('code').append('l');
});

$('.click').click(function(){
    $('.hover').mouseenter();
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/uC5Qg/)

Comment: Damn, 7 secondes, I had to remove my (upvoted) answer as useless :)